# Change appearance of already modified doi field in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting, biber

I already changed the `doi` field such that it includes a link on which the reader can click:

```
% make the doi a clickable hyperlink
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \mkbibacro{DOI}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref{%
    \href{https://doi.org/#1}{
      \nolinkurl{#1}
    }
  }{
    \nolinkurl{#1}
  }
}
```

The `doi` is now printed in capital letters, see the following screenshot, how do I change that to lowercase letters? In my understanding

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{#1}
```

should have done this, but it is not.

[image: Bibliography]

I am compiling with `xelatex biber xelatex xelatex` and here is the full `MWE`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\begin{filecontents*}{tmp_bib.bib} 
    @book{Peter1, 
        author={Peter Muller}, 
        title={My life as Peter Mueller}, 
        address={Peterstown}, 
        publisher={Petersen family},
        year={2017}
    } 
    @article{Klaus1,
        author = {Peter, Klaus and Petersen, Peter},
        title = {A research article about Peter Mueller},
        journal = {Intern. Journal on Science},
        year = {2018},
        volume = {33},
        pages = {000007},
        doi = {10.10}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
    style=authortitle,
    autocite=footnote,
    maxcitenames=1,
    backend=biber,
    ]
    {biblatex}
\addbibresource{tmp_bib.bib}

% change appearance of citations in footnotes
\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \printfield{journaltitle}%
      \setunit{\space}%
      \printtext[parens]{\printdate}%
    }
  }{}%
  \ifentrytype{book}{
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
      \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
      \setunit{\space}%
      \printtext[parens]{\printdate}%
    }%
  }{}
}

% make journal title not italic
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}

% make the doi a clickable hyperlink
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \mkbibacro{DOI}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref{%
    \href{https://doi.org/#1}{
      \nolinkurl{#1}
    }
  }{
    \nolinkurl{#1}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{One column on this page}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Even more text\footnotemark
    \footcitetext{Peter1}
        \item Note: an article\footnotemark
    \footcitetext{Klaus1}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `doi\addcolon\space` instead of `\mkbibacro{doi}\addcolon\space` ?

Comment: oh, well, for some reason I thought you couldn't simply enter text like that into the `DeclareFieldFormat` environment... will check when I'm at home, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) suggests in [the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471364/change-appearance-of-already-modified-doi-field-in-biblatex/471440#comment1187778_471364) you can simply write `doi\addcolon\space` instead of `\mkbibacro{doi}\addcolon\space`. So you would have

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  doi\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}%
}
```

Note the different line breaks and `%` at the end of lines to avoid spurious white space that the original definition might introduce. See also [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864).

[image: "doi" in lowercase letters in the bibliography]

---

If you want to change all acronym-like strings like "DOI", "URL", "ISBN", "ISSN" ... to lowercase, you can redefine the special macro `\mkbibacro` instead

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibacro}[1]{\MakeLowercase{#1}}
```

and retain the `\mkbibacro{DOI}\addcolon\space`.