# Replace the 'doi' keyword for all entries in a bibliography with \aiDoiSquare icon from academicons package

Tags: biblatex, biber, fontawesome, academicons

I am currently making my CV and using the `biblatex/biber` combo for bibliography management.

For visual pizazz, I wish to replace the keyword `doi` for each entry in the generated bibliography with the icon `\aiDoiSquare` from the `academicons` package. How can this be achieved?

Here is a MWE (using the `article` class for now)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, sorting=none,
  maxbibnames=50, eprint=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{academicons}    

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

Let us cite \cite{sigfridsson} for this doi question.

% Somehow replace the keyword 'doi' in all entries of the generated bibliography 
% with the '\aiDoiSquare' icon from the 'academicons' package.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/471364/35864

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using the `doi` formatting directive?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{academicons}
\usepackage{graphicx} % required for scalebox

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, sorting=none,
  maxbibnames=50, eprint=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \raisebox{-1.5pt}{\scalebox{1.4}{\aiDoiSquare}}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{kastenholz,sigfridsson}

% Somehow replace the keyword 'doi' in all entries of the generated bibliography
% with the '\aiDoiSquare' icon from the 'academicons' package.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
% Local Variables:
% TeX-engine: xetex
% End:
```

[image]

Comment: @moewe Yes, already corrected. I missed that, for the lack of other XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX features in the document, and as I didn't know the `academicons` package.

Comment: @moewe I think the doc does not even compile with `pdflatex`

Comment: @gusbrs Is there any way to increase the size of the icon? It is too small for my taste. I tried `\big`, but it errored out.

Comment: @Krishna Compile it did, the previous screenshot was really taken from it (no wonder it didn't look good...  :-)

Comment: @Krishna It does if you press enter a lot.

Comment: @Krishna Probably a scalebox will do, is the hint enough, or would you like that to be included in the answer?

Comment: @gusbrs done. I am satisfied with `\adjustbox{scale=1.2}{\aiDoi}`. Marked as accepted and upvoted. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Krishna Oh! I was preparing it. I'll include it in the answer, it might be of interest.

Comment: @moewe, As to "if you press enter a lot", it would certainly inspire Paulo Cereda to a classical "You are mean."   :-)

Comment: I have a feeling that the larger version of the icon pushes the lines a bit further apart then usual, so I guess there is a limit to the scaling. Of course one could try shifting the icon down a tiny bit to centre it and to distribute the line spread.

Comment: @moewe Yes, I overdid it a bit on purpose, as the effect was required by the OP. Which mentioned was happy with 1.2 rather than 1.4.

Comment: Mhh, I'm sure I'm quite mean at times, but in this instance I'd like to object, Your Honour: Pressing enter was how I compiled the document when I worked on an answer.

Comment: @moewe Am I Pushing it? :) "Of course one could try shifting the icon down a tiny bit to centre it and to distribute the line spread." - how exactly?

Comment: @moewe Oh, but it so read as "if you thoroughly ignore all the errors LaTeX throws at you".

Comment: @Krishna `raisebox`?

Comment: @moewe Okay, but how to automatically calculate the height (considering baseline-skip etc.) and re-center it? Can you please help with a code snippet with this? if gusbrs does not mind it, you could edit the answer suitably.

Comment: @Krishna I have absolutely no idea ;-) That's why I'm just shouting from the sidelines in the comments and not actually typing up an answer. Trial and error suggests `\raisebox{-2pt}{\scalebox{1.4}{\aiDoiSquare}}` sort of looks alright, but it would definitely be nicer to calculate that automatically.

Comment: @Krishna I added the raisebox as well. (Btw, I did not accept the suggested edit, because the answer does not use `adjustbox`, but `scalebox`, which is provided by `graphicx`)